# Kivy: I'm trying to use MapView and I get the following error: "Downloader error: HTTPError('403 Client Error: Forbidden for url:...)"

Tags: python, kivy, openstreetmap

I'm trying to integrate MapView in a python-kivy application.

Just for test I run the following code:

```
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView
from kivy.app import App

class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mapview = MapView(zoom=11, lat=50.6394, lon=3.057)
        return mapview

MapViewApp().run()
```

But I receive the error: `Downloader error: HTTPError('403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/11/1039/687.png',)`

I really cannot find why this doesn't work.

If anyone can help me I'll be extremely thankful.

Comment: I've been using a MapView for a project for the past couple months. Has been working great. All of a sudden it's no longer working and I've been getting this error too.

Comment: is this the first time you've tried to use a MapView? If that's the case, perhaps there is something wrong with OpenStreetMap rather than on our end.

Comment: Wrong or no user-agent set? Please see [OSM's tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem uninstalling mapview module with `garden uninstall mapview` and ago installed again: `garden install mapview`.
If your target platform is android try clear cache: `buildozer android clean` and ago rebuild your APK.